# How do I insert a word if the string has more than one space in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following code,

```
String s = "    Hello I'm a       multi spaced String"
```

In string s, there are multiple (indeterminate) spaces; but, I need to print it as `%temp%Hello I'm a%temp%multi spaced String`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use regex `\s{2,}` and `replaceAll()` method like this:

```
s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}","%temp%");
```

**Output**

```
%temp%Hello I'm a%temp%multi spaced String
```

**Code**

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String s = "    Hello I'm a       multi spaced String";
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}","%temp%");
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a complicated way of saying `"  +"`

Comment: @Bohemian I don't this `"  +"` will work with `tab` spaces.

Comment: Both question title and question content only mention "space", not "whitespace". Even the example only uses ordinary spaces. I'm a big believer in the KISS principle.

Comment: @Bohemian, This is the exact answer for what i'm need for my case! and I'm not a believer of  "Keep it simple, stupid" principle.Because i don't know it.

Comment: @Bohemian , If you Know how to insert word when string has `+<tab>word`  please answer on this post :) thanks for your help brother :D

Comment: @MohanSingh I don't understand what you want to do, but it sounds like a different question - if so, please ask a new question.

Comment: Okay bro. I will post... :D

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular expression like `\s\s+` which matches a white space followed by one or more additional whitespaces. Something like,

```
String s = "    Hello I'm a       multi spaced String";
s = s.replaceAll("\\s\\s+", "%temp%");
System.out.println(s);
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
%temp%Hello I'm a%temp%multi spaced String
```

Comment: Wow it works! You are save my time brother. Thanks lot :D